# Vue and Quasar - Module '"../../node_modules/vue/types"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I've been trying to solve this issue for a while now. I'm trying to port a project created using "vue create" to a project created using "quasar create". However, I get the following error when I try to use one of my component.vue files in the quasar project:

> Module '"../../node_modules/vue/types"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'

[image: The error]

My import statement looks like this:
`import { defineComponent } from 'vue'`

Is there a way to fix this? I've been searching for a solution for hours but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. Replacing the import statement with the following seems to have solved the issue:
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api